# Facebook redirect if not logged in

Tags: javascript, facebook, redirect

I'm using Facebook Auth and I'm trying to add an automatic redirect from interior pages to the log in page if the user is not logged in or they haven't authorized my app, and that part works fine. The problem I'm having is that when you arrive on index.php, it redirects you to index.php again, and again, infinitely. I've tried numerous things, like if (location.href == "index.php") do nothing, else redirect, but nothing I try works.

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === 'connected') {
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    window.location = "index.php";
  } else {
    window.location = "index.php";
  }
});
```

Comment: Why not just remove this from the index page ?  Also, have you tried alert(location.href); to see that it is indeed index.php ?

Comment: I have the correct URL. I have the code in a separate facebook.php file that I require on both the index page and the interior pages... in order to remove it from the index page I'd have to create two facebook.php files, one for public pages and one for private pages? That's redundant?

Comment: Try commenting out `window.location = "index.php";` and adding `console.log('connected');` before the end of each block (replacing 'connected' with 'not_authorized' or 'neither' for the other blocks). Let us know what shows up in the console on the index page so we can help you debug..

Comment: any solutions to this? Will drive me crazy!